# Ruby on Rails: Execute POST from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I want to use a rake task to seed some user data in my database for manual testing. Because of the complexity of my tables and business logic, the easiest way for me to do this would be to execute POSTs to my user_controller from the rake task. With RSpec (and FactoryGirl) I can do

```
   describe "POST create" do
        it "registers a new user" do
            @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
            user = attributes_for(:user)
            response = post( :create, user: user)
            response.status.should eql(200)
        end
    end
```

How can I use the 'post' helper in my rake task?

Comment: Put the code your controller calls on the post action in a "service" class, new one up in the rake task and call the method on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a `lib/tasks/seed_post.rake` the name of the file doesn't matter

and put the following code in it

```
namespace :seed do
  task :posts => :environment do
    50.times do |i|
      # it's your own problem to generate the following user, params so that it works
      Post::CreationService.perform(user, params)
    end
  end
end
```

now you can call the task using.. `rake seed:posts` or `zeus rake seed:posts` or `bundle exec rake seed:posts` depending whether you are using zeus or bundler or whatever...

what really matters is that your call should be in the form of

`rake namespace_you_defined:task_name_you_defined`

also you have to change the controller create to become

```
def create
  @post = Post::CreationService.perform(current_user, post_params)
  # instead of this old code i'm assuming you are using
  @post = current_user.posts.create!(post_params)
  ...
end
```

also add a this file

```
# app/services/post/creation_service.rb
class Post::CreationService
  def self.perform(current_user, params)
    current_user.posts.create!(params)
   end
end
```

Comment: This is helpful, thank you, but the part I don't know is how to do the POSTing. Can I include the test helpers in my rake task?

Comment: I guess that is not possible... but if you are familiar with service objects.. you can convert the `POST #create` in the controller to a service object and use it in the rake task

Comment: @BradUrani i've edited the answer.. hope it can help even a little... cause i don't know how exactly your logic or controller look like.

Comment: Turns out what I actually wanted to do in the question is not a great idea. This is much better. I just happen to be refactoring a project with bloated controllers and was looking for shortcuts until I could actually refactor it

Comment: The way i refactored the controller is called `service object` pattern. You can read more about it

Comment: Here is the updated link for the article https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/the-publish-subscribe-pattern-on-rails